# What is the difference between regular softmax and sampled softmax?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, softmax

I am learning seq2seq neural model and I get confused at the regular softmax and sampled softmax. I was told that the sampled softmax is mainly for large vocabulary. So can anyone explain the difference between the two intuitively?